# How to change the x axis scale ranges from 00:00 to 23:00 in plotly.js heatmap chart

Tags: python, html, plotly, plotly.js

I want to put fixed time range on x-axis scale which has to range from 00:00 to 23:00 how to do that in plotly.js I can able to get the x-axis scale from 00:00 to 24:00 in plotly using plotly.js I couldn't able to get it how to achieve it

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/plotly.js/2.24.2/plotly.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="heatmapDiv"></div>
  <script>
    // Data
    var data = {
      "08:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 0.0},
      "09:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 2.42},
      "10:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 2.698},
      "11:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 7.174},
      "12:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 5.32},
      "13:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 4.08},
      "14:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 1.234},
      "16:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 10.5},
      "17:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 6.028},
      "18:00": {"2023-06-20 (Tuesday)": 3.806},

    };
    // Extract the time and date values
    var times = Object.keys(data);
    var dates = Object.keys(data[times[0]]);

    // Prepare the data for the heatmap
    var z = dates.map(function(date) {
      return times.map(function(time) {
        var value = data[time][date];
        if (isNaN(value)) {
          return 0; // Assign 0 to NaN values
        } else if (value === null) {
          return -1; // Assign -1 to represent empty spaces
        } else {
          return value;
        }
      });
    });

    // Create the custom color scale
    var customColorScale = [
       ['0.0', 'rgb(189, 177, 180)'],
    ['0.111111111111', 'rgb(106, 215, 39)'],
    ['0.222222222222', 'rgb(7, 184, 48)'],
    ['0.333333333333', 'rgb(253,174,97)'],
    ['0.444444444444', 'rgb(254,224,144)'],
    ['0.555555555556', 'rgb(232, 122, 19)'],
    ['0.666666666667', 'rgb(214, 103, 114)'],
    ['0.777777777778', 'rgb(176, 23, 38)'],
    ['0.888888888889', 'rgb(176, 23, 38)'],
    ['1.0', 'rgb(179, 9, 26)']
    ];

    // Create the heatmap trace
    var heatmapTrace = {
      x: times,
      y: dates,
      z: z,
      type: 'heatmap',
      colorscale: customColorScale,
      colorbar: {
        title: 'Value',
        titleside: 'right',
      },
    };
    var times = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 24; i++) {
  var time = i.toString().padStart(2, '0') + ':00'; // Format the time as HH:00
  times.push(time);
}
    // Create the layout
// Create the layout
var layout = {
  title: 'Heatmap',
  xaxis: {
    title: 'Time',
    type: 'category', // Specify the type as 'category'
    tickvals: times,
    ticktext: times,

  },
  yaxis: {
    tickmode: 'array',
    tickvals: dates,
    ticktext: dates.map(function(date) {
      var weekday = new Date(date).toLocaleDateString('en-US', { weekday: 'long' });
      return weekday; // Return the weekday instead of the full date
    }),
  },
};


    // Create the figure
    var plotData = [heatmapTrace];
    Plotly.newPlot('heatmapDiv', plotData, layout);
  </script>
</body>
</html>
```

in my original chart x axis is ranges from 08:00 to 18:00 but i need range from 00:00 to 23:00 how to do it kindly help me through this